# How to initialize static members which belong to global scope in c++

Tags: c++, scope

In my project, there are two classes named Configuration. One is in the namespace common. The other has no namespace, so it's in global scope.The class in global scope is like this:
Configuration.h:

```
class Configuration
{
    public:
        static int a;
        static string b;
        void func();
}
```

Configuration.cpp:

```
#include "Configuration.h"
int ::Configuration a; //ok
std::string ::Configuration b;//error,the complier treat it like this "std::string::Configuration"
```

The message from complier is like this:
***configuration.cpp:17: error: ‘std::string::Configuration’ has not been declared***

How to solve this problem, and why the complier treat "std::string  ::Configuration" as "std::string::Configuration"?

Comment: `Class` is wrong. Don't post bogus code here please. Also post error messages as verbatim text not as picture. Best provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: As I write in the question, there is another class named Configuration in namespace common and I also need to use it. If I write like this `int Configuration::a; std::string Configuration::b`, the complier prompt like this:reference to ‘Configuration’ is ambiguous

Comment: `Class` is wrong nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the global scope explicitly here, you can just omit the `::`.

```
int Configuration::a;
std::string Configuration::b;
```

If you really want to, you need to create one extra level of indirection somehow:

```
typedef ::Configuration conf;
std::string conf::b;
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves this problem. But why the complier  prompts error: ***‘std::string::Configuration’ has not been declared***

Comment: @Lianshuai Because the compiler sees the declaration as `std::string::Configuration`.